# Adding open source car library to Android Studio, can not access Classes

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add this library from Git to my Android Studio project https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/

No matter what I try I cant seem to add the module correctly.
Any tips in how I might go about to add it correctly?

Comment: What have you tried and what issue do you get?

Comment: I now how to clone the repo. I have tried to add it as a module to an app I have created to try and access the classes from that module.
One error I got was: service.
app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project